# 12v DC rocker switch with LED, how to use in an AC application?

Tags: led, switches, ac, dc

I have ten of these 20A 12V DC switches:

[image: switch]

I'd like to install them in a 120V AC (typical U.S. home) application where their entire function would be to light their own built-in LED when switched on… so, no need for the switch to actually power on and off a device as they're intended.

How can I do this safely?

---

FWIW: this would be for a simple tally board for use in a kindergarten classroom.

Comment: `FWIW: this would be for a simple tally board for use in a kindergarten classroom.` You have no idea how to work with mains voltage, and you want to put this in a classroom? ***NO. BAD. DONT.*** Get 8 AA batteries and be done with it.

Comment: You'll need a simple 12VDC power supply. Even if the LEDs require as much as 20 mA each, a supply with 0.5 to 1.0 A current capacity will be more than enough.

Comment: @Passerby Thanks. That's good information. Can you tell me how I might do this with batteries or point me to a resource.

Comment: 8 AA batteries in series is 1.5V * 8 = 12V. Wire to the LED switch as per the directions on the side of the switch. Done.

Comment: @DaveTweed Thanks. Can you explain how I might wire this?

Comment: @Passerby Okay. This seems like a good solution. Thank you. Wiring all 10 off the same battery pack?

Comment: what is  a "tally board for use in a kindergarten classroom."

Comment: Yes,  you can easily wire all ten in parallel off a single pack.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 By "tally board", I simply mean a thing that keeps a count. In this case, 1 through 10.

Comment: @Passerby Got it. I hadn't considered batteries. That is probably the simplest… and by far the safest… approach. Many thanks.

Comment: I would use a calculator and press Clear 1+ ===== to count. or total number of students <enter> -1 ======= and count down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of safety, forget using mains voltage or even a ac to dc adapter. Simply use batteries. Normal alkaline batteries have a voltage of 1.5V, and 8 in series will provide the 12V these switches need for the led.

These automotive switches have an led with a resistor selected for 20 mA at 12V, so no extra parts are needed to enable the leds.

Simply connect the 8 batteries in series,  and connect that in parallel with the 10 switches. You can even buy an 8xAA battery holder.

Comment: Just to close the loop here, I wired this all up with an 8 AA battery holder (Amazon, $3), and it worked like a champ. I even wired in a simple on/off for the entire board. Thanks for the battery suggestion! Much easier than what I had initially planned.

Comment: @Sam good to hear.